# Angular - CodeAnywhere - You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core". This is an error

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, codeanywhere

Hey im trying to install Angular Cli but i keep getting failed package install. Then i try to start the server and it says You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core". This is an error.

[image: Failed to install package]

Comment: can you please update your question with package.json file ?

Answer (score 4):

Check if you're in the project folder in terminal

Answer (score 1):

first check the node

```
node -v
```

and npm are install correctly

```
npm -v
```

then try again with

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

then you add it in ts file

```
const _core = require("@angular/core");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved this problem on my machine.

I first ran `npm install @angular/core`.

Then I ran `npm install --save`.

When both installs had successfully completed I ran `npm serve` and received an error saying

```
"Versions of @angular/compiler-cli and typescript could not be determined.
The most common reason for this is a broken npm install.

Please make sure your package.json contains both @angular/compiler-cli and typescript in
devDependencies, then delete node_modules and package-lock.json (if you have one) and
run npm install again."
```

I then deleted my node_modules folder as well as my package-lock.json folder.

After I deleted those folders I ran `npm install --save` once more.

I ran `npm start` and received another error. This error said `Error: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/core'`.

I ran `npm install @angular-devkit/core --save`.

Finally, I ran `npm start` and the project started!

Answer (score 0):

First ensure you have `@angular/core` install, else run:

```
npm install @angular/core
```

This should get `@angular/core` install in you node_module and also update itself in your `package.json`. Also ensure that you're not using an old version of node and NPM, else run from your terminal:

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

Then you can add into your js file .

```
const core_1 = require("@angular/core");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some issue with node-sass in codeanywhere due to some permission exceptions.
The workaround is go to /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/ and delete the node_modules folder and then run sudo npm install again
create a new project using ng new and try running it . It will work

Answer (score 0):

### How to use

Run `npm install` inside this project folder to install all dependencies.

Make sure you use the latest version of the CLI (upgrade guide below)

Run `ng serve` to see the app in action (try `npm start` in case `ng serve` fails).

### How to upgrade the CLI

Run the below commands - only use "sudo" on Mac/ Linux.

```
sudo npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli

npm cache clean --force

sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

### Incase if it fails too

Delete 'node_modules' folder and 'package-lock.json' file from your project directory

Run the below commands in the given order

```
npm install

npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular

npm link
```